# vim with tagbar and YouCompleteMe is very slow

Tags: vim

I am writing linux c code with vim.I install plugin tagbar to jump to function definition，and install plugin YouCompleteMe to perform code completion.
But I find vim is running slowly, and I forbid tagbar, vim is faster.But tagbar is possible to me, is there is plugin that can instead of tagbar or how to deal with the two plugins to let vim faster?

Answer (score 0):

Vim Taglist plugin bay be helpful